# Navigation Back Bar not changing from previous view title

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

I've been trying to change the text for my back button. I've changed everything from the previous view's back button text, to the visible view's back button text, to setting the back button equal to a new button and changing its text. Alas, all I get is the text of the previous views title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the title of the back button item, but you can replace the back button directly.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

The trick is to set it on **the pushing view controller**, not on the one displaying the back button item.

You can set it in `viewDidLoad` of your pushing view controller. If you want to custom the back button according to the pushed view controllers, set it in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: The one case I didn't try, new button on the old view. Wonderful thanks

Comment: It wasn't obvious for me at first too ;)